# How to click on an image to display the details of that image (that data is taken from firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter

How can I know which event I clicked on? How to click on an image to display the details of that image (that data is taken from firebase). I can't find a solution to this problem, please help!

```
Widget _allUsers(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder <List<MatHangSnapshot>>(
  stream: getAllMatHangFromFirebase(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData)
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    else {
      return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount:  2),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: GridTile(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChiTietNongSan()),
                  );
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.network(snapshot.data[index].mh.image, width: 150, height: 150,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              footer: Column(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text(snapshot.data[index].mh.tenMH, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Giá: ${snapshot.data[index].mh.gia.toString()}/kg",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red),),
                  )
                ],
              )
```

Comment: Please, include your Firestore database structure and the `MatHangSnapshot` class.

Answer (score 0):

accept the image via the constructor of  `ChiTietNongSan` class then make your `onPressed` look like this

```
onPressed: () {
   //change this to your actual image
   var image = snapshot.data[index]["image"];

   Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChiTietNongSan(image)),
   );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image in the `FlatButton`'s `onPressed` method, the same way you're displaying it in the `Image.network` widget by using the code below:

```dart
snapshot.data[index].mh.image
```

And you can use it in your `onPressed` like this:

```dart
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    print(snapshot.data[index].mh.image);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChiTietNongSan()),);
  },
    ...
)
```

The important thing with knowing which exact image you clicked on is the `index` and you can use that to get any information you need from the `MatHangSnapshot` class.